# Is there any advantage to using find method and includes method together?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

It does not seem to make sense to use `includes` and `find` together as follows

```
User.includes(:friends).find(1)
```

The number of records to be retrieved is only one, and if `user.friends` is called, the number of query calls will be the same as without includes.

Is there any advantage to using find method and includes method together?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no benefit to using `includes` with `find`. Two queries(1 for finding the object and 1 for loading the association) will be fired in either case.
The below code fires the same queries as your code:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.friends    # wherever you need to use the associated friends objects.
```